# How complexity differs from calling a function actually n times or putting inside a loop that iterates n times?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Let's say the function simply prints the elements of an array. I know the time complexity of the following loop version will be O(n).

```
static void printArray(int[] myArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Let's say the print statement is written for the length of the myArray, the complexity is same or not?

```
static void printArray(int[] myArray)
{
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println(myArray[i++]);
    System.out.println(myArray[i++]);
    System.out.println(myArray[i++]);
    .
    .
    .
    System.out.println(myArray[i++]);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well other than generating more code, it is still O(n)

Comment: @OldProgrammer Then the only difference is writability and readability I guess, thank you.

Comment: They're both LINEAR TIME / O(n), meaning the length of time required to complete the algorithm will be DIRECTLY PROPORTIONAL to the amount of input. But the second version is a COMPLETE WASTE OF TIME and will get you FIRED. See the difference?  ;)

Comment: Technically, the second option requires a new program for each input length. So you can't really say that the time complexity of the PROGRAM is *Θ(n)*. It would be *O(1)*, because for any such program, the time doesn't actually depend on the size of your input anymore. It will just execute as many times as you have that instruction in your code, a constant time. However, the time complexity of the PROBLEM is still *O(n)*. And if, hypothetically, those 3 dots had been correct java syntax that actually produces *n* executions of your print, then it would be *O(n)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a philosophical question.

Technically, the second option requires a new program for each input length. So you can't really say that the time complexity of the **program** is *Θ(n)*. Instead, it would be *O(1)* because for any such program, the time doesn't actually depend on the size of your input anymore. It will just execute as many times as you have that instruction in your code: a constant number. But such programs aren't really solutions to the problem for a general array, rather to the special-case problem when the length of the array is known, and thus constant.

The time complexity of the **problem** is still *O(n)*. And if, hypothetically, those three dots had been correct Java syntax that actually produces *n* executions of your print, then it would be O(n). And you can continue this argument: You could have a program that produces your second code snippet as a separate program, and then executes it. This would also be *O(n)*.

So it boils down to how you view it. If you want to be formal, you need to define a computation model (and delve into the realm of [Turing Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine), [Random Access Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine) etc.) and ask your question in relation to that.